# Jetpack Compose - Update element in all lists

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose

For example I have two screens in my App, each with a List.
The Post with ID 1 exists in both lists.

When I now update the Post with ID 1 in Screen 1 it doesn't reflect the changes in the List of Screen 2.
The problem is I cannot query through both lists because they are in two different screens.

The change on Post 1 gets send to my database so when I restart the app or the Screen, both screens are up to date.
It just doesnt reflect the change when the other Screen is in a cached/background state.

I have `saveState = true` on my Navigation so it doesnt fetch the data again every time I switch between both screens.

How do I update the List in Screen 2 while I'm on Screen 1?

P.S I'm using GraphQL Apollo + MVVM + Clean Architecture

(No code answer needed, just some hint on how it could be done or resources to look into is enough)

Comment: "How do I update the List in Screen 2 while I'm on Screen 1?"  - You need to observe changes in the database. This can easily be done using libraries like Room, SQLDelight or Realm using LiveData, RxJava or Kotlin Flow .. or your own implementation in some sort of Repository/Dao that tracks CRUD operations and updates client using an Observer pattern - as you are using "Clean Archtiecture" this should be quite trivial to introduce.

Comment: Are you talking about a Sinlge Source of Truth system? I had some problems with this approach due to the bad documentation of GraphQL Apollo. Could you explain it with Room in a little more detail? Or is there any good resources on it?
Also forgot to mention, the data in my app is constantly changing, its a social media app with user generated content.

Comment: Not specifically a SSoT, but it was inferred as you stated you have a database. I strongly suggest you treat the database as a SSoT if you don't already (although this is what you update?). GraphQL, issues implementing a SSoT etc .. seem to be implementation details you need to overcome as it looks like you are suffering side effects of not doing this (I thought GraphQL has subscriptions via web sockets?). Your question doesn't really go into detail, about how this is archtiected so I any answers could be met with follow up comments on specifcs and omiited details - like your first comment.

Comment: Like the other comment have said, its hard to assume how your code is implemented.I would simply expect the "second screen" to be updated once I navigate to it, given that both screens observe to same repository/viewmodel, I can't think of any fancy or complicated things if my requirement is "the second screen should be updated from any actions from the first screen"